# Déjà Dup backup Restore Failure

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I tried to restore a Deja Dup backup and it fails, I get an unknown error that has a trace back that is below.  If there is anyway to just open the backup folders that would be enough for me to at least manually transfer what I need any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1337, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1370, in do_backup
    globals.archive_dir).set_values()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 697, in set_values
    self.get_backup_chains(partials + backend_filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 819, in get_backup_chains
    map(add_to_sets, filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 809, in add_to_sets
    if set.add_filename(filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 96, in add_filename
    self.set_manifest(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 127, in set_manifest
    remote_filename)
AssertionError: ('duplicity-full.20130313T005245Z.manifest.gpg', 'duplicity-full.20130313T005245Z.manifest')
```